# Perform connected_components with Boost adjacency_list where VertexList=listS

Tags: c++, graph, boost-graph

I use Boost Graph Library in a project and it is declared as:

```
typedef adjacency_list <listS, listS, undirectedS, TrackInformation, LinkInformation> TracksConnectionGraph;
```

Things are going fine until I have to call connected_components on my graph.

```
typedef std::map<TracksConnectionGraph::vertex_descriptor, TracksConnectionGraph::vertices_size_type> component_type;
component_type component;
boost::associative_property_map< component_type > component_map(component);

int num_components = connected_components(tracks_connection_graph_, component_map);
```

The problem seems to be that if the VertexList=listS, I do not have vertex_index as a property of my vertex. This makes connected_components give me errors like theses:

> /usr/local/include/boost-1_39/boost/property_map.hpp:
>   In member function 'R
>   boost::iterator_property_map::operator[](typename
>   boost::property_traits::key_type)
>   const [with RandomAccessIterator =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator
>   , IndexMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map,
>   boost::detail::error_property_not_found,
>   const
>   boost::detail::error_property_not_found&,
>   boost::vertex_index_t>, T =
>   boost::default_color_type, R =
>   boost::default_color_type&]':

So the question is: how do I add vertex_index as a property of my vertices?

If I add it, does it mean that whenever I call add_vertex, remove_vertex and such, I have to update this information for each vertex?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `vertex_index` property to the definition of your graph type (in the vertex property template argument to `adjacency_list`, change `TrackInformation` to `property<vertex_index_t, size_t, TrackInformation>`).  Before calling the algorithm, you will need to fill in the property map using a loop such as:

```
size_t index = 0;
BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, tracks_connection_graph_, TracksConnectionGraph) {
  put(vertex_index, g, v, index++);
}
```