# remove_vertex when the graph VertexList=vecS

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have a Boost Graph with VertexList=vecS.

```
typedef adjacency_list <listS, vecS, undirectedS, TrackInformation, LinkInformation> TracksConnectionGraph;
```

Now I want to iterate through my vertices and remove those that have a specific property. How can I do this?

The problem is whenever I call remove_vertex, the iterator to the vertices in the graph along with the vertex descriptors are invalidated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible (in a reasonable time) with `vecS` as a template parameter. Look what Boost documentation says:

> If the `VertexList` template parameter of the `adjacency_list` was `vecS`, then all vertex descriptors, edge descriptors, and iterators for the graph are invalidated by this operation. <...> If you need to make frequent use of the `remove_vertex()` function the `listS` selector is a much better choice for the `VertexList` template parameter.

In case of `listS` the iterators are not invalidated by calling `remove_vertex` unless the iterator is pointing to the actual vertex that was removed.

Comment: The problem with listS is that I cannot get connected_components to work with it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183186/perform-connected-components-with-boost-adjacency-list-where-vertexlistlists

Answer (score 3):

May be, before iteration you can make special "Trash" vertex, during iteration you connect all nodes-for-deletion to that Trash-vertex and, after iteration, delete all "Trash-connected" vertices?

Comment: This is well worth investigating.

Comment: But how to keep track of the trash vertex when deleting its neighbours invalidates the vertex_descriptor?

Answer (score 3):

Your edges are stored in an std::vector. If you have N vertices, then all vertices are numbered from 0 to N. If you delete one, then your vertices will be renumbered from o to N-1. Therefor, your descriptor will be invalidated.

However, there might be a work arround :
– iterate from N down to 0
– test your node and delete it if necessary

This supposes (and I'm not sure, but rather confident) that it will only renumber the vertices **after** the one you've just deleted.

If you do this manipulation a lot, it might be rather slow depending on your graph's size.

If that approach doesn't work, you'll have to build a new graph from the old one (by pre-computing how many vertices and edges you will have, this might actually be reasonnably fast).

So, sorry, no real answer, but I hope you'll manage to get something out of it.

Comment: This would be nice if you just operated on the vector. But `adjacency_list` manages it and needs to reindex the edges anyways. It might choose to reallocate the vector after `n` removals (again invalidating _all_ iterators). Finally, reverse iterating `vertices(graph)` isn't guaranteed to be equivalent to reverse iterating the internal vector of vertices